# Duplicate Values SQL - Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm stuck in a problem with SQL on MS Access..

The thing is, I have:
Weeks that can be duplicate as a person is in two different departments, or sales channel, area manager name, or both in the same week..

What I want? I want to sum the amounts of Total Inbounds, etc(there are 70 different) in the same week when I have the bigger amount..

Great, managed to do that, BUT, when Total Inbounds and SRs Created are equal in a determined week it duplicate the week.. I don't have a third value that put it here, maybe use the first one, but I don't know how to do it.. :/

Anyone has an idea how to manage it?

My SQL is bellow, thanks!

```
SELECT 
        Raw.[NT Login],
        Raw.[Fiscal Week],
        MaxDuplicate.[Manager Name],
        MaxDuplicate.[Area Manager Name],
        MaxDuplicate.[Sales Channel],
        MaxDuplicate.Department,
        Raw.[Fiscal Month Name],
        Raw.[Fiscal Quarter],  
        MaxDuplicate.[Functional Name],
        Raw.Location,
        Raw.Partner,
        MaxDuplicate.Queue,
        MaxDuplicate.[Queue Status Desc],
        Raw.[Sub Region],
        Sum(Raw.[SRs Created]) AS [SRs Created],
        Sum(Raw.[Total Inbounds]) AS [Total Inbounds],
        Raw.[Weekly Lag]
FROM Raw 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Raw.[NT Login], 
            Raw.[Fiscal Week], 
            Raw.[Manager Name],
            Raw.[Area Manager Name],
            Raw.[Sales Channel],
            Raw.Department,
            Raw.[Functional Name],
            Raw.Queue,
            Raw.[Queue Status Desc]         
            FROM Raw 
            INNER JOIN 
                (SELECT 
                    Raw.[NT Login], 
                    Raw.[Fiscal Week], 
                    MAX(Raw.[Total Inbounds]) AS [Total Inbounds],
                    MAX(Raw.[SRs Created]) AS [SRs Created]
                        FROM Raw 
                        GROUP BY Raw.[NT Login], Raw.[Fiscal Week]) AS Max
                    ON Raw.[NT Login] = Max.[NT Login] 
                    AND Raw.[Fiscal Week] = Max.[Fiscal Week]
                    WHERE 
                        Raw.[Total Inbounds] = Max.[Total Inbounds]
                        AND Raw.[SRs Created] = Max.[SRs Created]) AS MaxDuplicate 
ON Raw.[NT Login] = MaxDuplicate.[NT Login] 
AND Raw.[Fiscal Week] = MaxDuplicate.[Fiscal Week]
GROUP BY Raw.[NT Login], 
         Raw.[Fiscal Week],
         MaxDuplicate.[Manager Name],
         MaxDuplicate.[Area Manager Name],
         MaxDuplicate.[Sales Channel],
         MaxDuplicate.Department,
         Raw.[Fiscal Month Name],
         Raw.[Fiscal Quarter],  
         MaxDuplicate.[Functional Name],
         Raw.Location,
         Raw.Partner,
         MaxDuplicate.Queue,
         MaxDuplicate.[Queue Status Desc],
         Raw.[Sub Region],
         Raw.[Weekly Lag]
```

Comment: If you shorten up this query to only what needs to be there to ask your question it will be easier/more likely to be answered (I am assuming all the sums for example, are not relevant to the problem